# Line spacing within an item in a list created with tasks package

Tags: line-spacing, tasks

This is about using the `tasks` package.
I was looking for an option (like in the commented line in the MWE below) to tweak the spacing between the lines inside an item (a `task` item). I couldn't find such an option in the documentation. Is there a way to decrease the space between the lines in task a) or task b) in the MWE?

Complementary question: is there a way to reduce the space between paragraphs (task c) as an example)?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tasks}

\def\sample{This is some sample text we will use to create a somewhat longer text spanning more than a line.}
%\settasks{interline-space = 1em} % "interline-space" doesn't exist

\begin{document}
    \begin{tasks}
        \task line 1\\ line 2
        \task \sample\ \sample \\ \sample
        \task \sample\par\sample
    \end{tasks}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is is something like that you want?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage{setspace}
\def\sample{This is some sample text we will use to create a somewhat longer text spanning more than a line.}
%\settasks{interline-space = 1em} % "interline-space" doesn't exist
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{tasks}{\setstretch{.6}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tasks}
        \task line 1\\ line 2
        \task \sample\ \sample \\ \sample
        \task \sample\par\sample
    \end{tasks}
This is some sample text we will use to create a somewhat longer text spanning more than a line. This is some sample text we will use to create a somewhat longer text spanning more than a line. This is some sample text we will use to create a somewhat longer text spanning more than a line.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This solution affects the space between paragraphs [SBP] as well, which is good in most applications but I need to control this space separately (hence the complementary Q). Currently I need to make the paragraph line spacing [PLS] smaller but the SBP needs to remain unaffected. In the near future I will have to make SBP same as PLS. Maybe there's a way to tweak the spaces independently? Thanks for the answer and for the {tasks} tag [Is 'etoolbox' doing anything here?]

Comment: @alwaysask: Well, I don't know what it is you call SBP and PLS. Standard LaTeX defines only `\baselineskip` and `parskip`. You always can change the value of parskip each time you need it… As for the `etoolbox` package, it defines `AtBeginEnvironment`, which I use to make `\setstretch` local to the environment.

Comment: It's not that I call something SBP/PLS. Those are local (i.e. my_comment_wide) acronyms defined by the 3 words before the 1st occurrence of those abbreviations.  As for `etoolbox`, the above MWE builds without the explicit inclusion of the package, that's why I asked - never mind though.  Setting `parskip` globally (which doesn't do well in my case anyway) or with `\AtBeginEnvironment` has no effect in `tasks` environment. Can you provide an MWE please?

Comment: @alwaysask: I had tested a number of possibilities. The only one that worked was to define a `\mypar` command as `
\newcommand\mypar[1][4ex{\setlength\parskip{4ex}\par}` (the extravagant 4ex value is just for testing, and use `\mypar` instead of `\par`. Perhaps one could use etoolbox to patch the definition of \par `inside` the tasks environment. Not tested, though.